# Receive Weblogic Queue JMS message on Active MQ

Tags: java, jms, weblogic, activemq-classic, jbossfuse

We recently moved our application from Weblogic to JBOSS Fuse. As part of this move, we also had to change JMS implementation to Active MQ.
Due to some constraints, the client which was sending the request to Old Weblogic JMS queue will not be able to make changes to send the request to the new Active MQ. Is there a way where I can keep the client unchanged (change only the host and port to point to new servers) and receive the messages sent to Weblogic JMS queue (without a weblogic server ofcourse) and convert them to receive as a Active MQ message to process?

Answer (score 2):

No, JMS is not a protocol specification just an API.  Your client code using WebLogic JMS libraries is using an entirely different and proprietary protocol that ActiveMQ cannot understand.  You must use the ActiveMQ client library.

If you have a WebLogic server running then you can use a JMS bridge to bridge the Queue between WebSphere and ActiveMQ.